# How do I have a Windows installer support `/s` option?

Tags: windows

Per [this post](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Windows/4.4/com.vmware.horizon.windows-client-44-doc/GUID-F19EBDF6-20A3-4A8B-95AE-786CC74F26AF.html), `/s` option Disables the bootstrap splash screen and extraction dialog box, which prevents the display of interactive dialog boxes.

However, [conda installer](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/) doesn't seem to support this option

[image]

Comment: Not all installers support the same options.

Comment: There is no standard to arguments, this is all up to the developer(s) of the software.  Typically the documentation for the product would divulge this information. That said, generally, you can usually perform a few actions. For example run with `/?` or `-?` or `-help` or `--help` or `-h`. if none of those help, I tend to parse the file with `strings.exe` from Sysinternals. It helps if you know an existing command line switch to help locate the others. It maybe that the installer requests information during the install for which there are sensible defaults so other switches may be needed.